# MapKitView under TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, mapkit

I am developing an application in which I have to add tabBarController with mapKitView under it. Is there an ability to achieve this, because I've tried to drag mapKitView in storyboard on my tabBarController but seems that I can't do it in that way.

The only thing that I can do is to put a mapKitView inside each tabBarController child vc. But then I will need to make all of them equal. In example when I scroll my map on the first tab then when I switched to second tab the second map should be on the same place as my first map.

Sorry, if you can't understand my opinion, because of my bad english. Any ideas would be helpful coz I'm stuck here.

Comment: I think you should use a toolbar instead of a tabBar. This way, you don't change the map, it will be the same all time

Comment: what will be the use of placing mapview under tabbarcontroller ? you were not able to see it anyway..

Comment: I think Drizztneko right, you are find toolbar not tabbar.

Comment: Vote up for @Drizztneko comment as thats a good way to handle mapView and your goal but what you trying to achieve with 2 different tabs and same map at both places?

Comment: @nikhil84 My customer wants it to be on each tab, but scrollable only on the first tab. For the rest tabs it is needed just to switch to the first tab when clicked.